# Error from timestamp response

Tags: java, http, http-headers, timestamp

I have to get a timestamp from a tsa server. I am sending a file (converted in `byte[]`).
 But when I try to get a response it throws me a `NullPointerException`.

This is my code:

```
public static void timeStampServer () throws IOException{
        //String TSA_URL1    = "http://tsa.starfieldtech.com/";
        String TSA_URL2 = "http://ca.signfiles.com/TSAServer.aspx";
        //String TSA_URL3 = "http://timestamping.edelweb.fr/service/tsp";
        try {
            byte[] digest = leerByteFichero("C:\\deskSign.txt");

            TimeStampRequestGenerator reqgen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
            TimeStampRequest req = reqgen.generate(TSPAlgorithms.SHA1, digest);
            byte request[] = req.getEncoded();

            URL url = new URL(TSA_URL2);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/timestamp-query");

            con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(request.length));

            if (con.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException("Received HTTP error: " + con.getResponseCode() + " - " + con.getResponseMessage());
            }
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            TimeStampResp resp = TimeStampResp.getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(in).readObject());
            TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);
            response.validate(req);
            System.out.println(response.getTimeStampToken().getTimeStampInfo().getGenTime());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Im trying with 3 tsa server but any of them returns me a valid TSA. 
All of one throws a NullPointerException in 
"`TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);`".
 `TSA_URL2` throws a

> java.io.IOException: Received HTTP error: 411 - Length Required.

I dont know if the problem is in tsa server or in my code. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I forgot to say that leerByteFichero function just read a file and convert it to a byte[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of what I can see lies in your requests (NullPointer comes from an empty resp as you get no response). Specifically, the problem is you have no colon after your HTTP request headers. This makes the server fail to read an obligatory Content-length header. From [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) section 4.2 (HTTP doc):

> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822. **Each header field consists of
>   a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value**.

TL;DR:

change:

```
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/timestamp-query");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(request.length));
```

to:

```
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type:", "application/timestamp-query");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length:", String.valueOf(request.length));
```

Comment: You were right that's the problem. Now it throws this another exception:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in 'TimeStampResp' factory : org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUnknownTag when I create the TimeStampResp object

Comment: +1 this answer solves the initial question, for the new problem maybe it's better to ask another question.